# Why my char pointer do not store the value?

Tags: c

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int i=0;
char *arr[1000]; 
char* passwordCracker(int pass_size, char** pass, char* attempt,int n) {
    i=0;
    while(*attempt && i<pass_size){
        if(!strncmp(attempt,pass[i],strlen(pass[i]))){
            attempt+=strlen(pass[i]);
            arr[n] = pass[i];//I m stuck here,it does not assign the value  
            n++;
            printf("%s %d %d %p %s\n",attempt,i,n,arr[n],pass[i]);
            passwordCracker(pass_size,pass,attempt,n);
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
//checks for password attempt


int main(){
    int t; 
    scanf("%i", &t);
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
        int n=0; 
        scanf("%i", &n);
        char* *pass = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * n);
        for (int pass_i = 0; pass_i < n; pass_i++) {
            pass[pass_i] = (char *)malloc(10240 * sizeof(char));
            scanf("%s",pass[pass_i]);
        }
        char* attempt = (char *)malloc(512000 * sizeof(char));
        scanf("%s", attempt);
        int result_size;
        char* result = passwordCracker(n, pass, attempt,0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

when I am providing input:
 
1
6
because can do must we what
wedowhatwemustbecausewecan

> it does not assign the value to arr array ??
>   It always shows the null value in the pointer array

[Output of arr and others](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhF4D.png)

Comment: Do you really need `512000` `char`s?

Comment: source code debugger is a good tool. try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr[n] = pass[i];//I m stuck here,it does not assign the value  
n++;
printf("%s %d %d %p %s\n",attempt,i,n,arr[n],pass[i]);
```

value assigned, but you print n+1 value, try arr[n-1]

Answer (score 0):

Pointer can only hold the address you can put all the address in some particular array  variable and print that  array variable

Comment: The problem with my code was that I was printing arr[n] while not defining the value see arr[n]=pass[i] and the n++, without defining arr[n++].